Emojis in Angular html template
I am trying to insert emojis into my html code. On the plain html file it is working. And on my Angular component it shows blank squares.
Here is a code that I have used for both plain and Angular examples:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-weight:600"> &#128566; &#x1F636;</p>
</body>
</html>


Output in plain: Plain html example
Output in Angular: Angular Example

Show the angular code snippet of how you are trying to include the emoji's in the template.  My suspicion is the ngsanitize or whatever modern equivalent is for handling parsing the interpolation strings may be munging things but would be helpful to see a sample (stackblitz good for the framework things in general).

I am not quite sure, what snippet do you want, I am using the same code in my templateUrl: './component.html' file as in example.

Huh so I see what you're saying, actually adding interpolation in this case did make them render but I'm not entirely sure why they aren't rendered without the interpolation wrapping around em:
{{'&#128566;'}}


